# PHP - data from SQL db repeats itself

Tags: php, sql

I'm so sorry if this doesn't make any sense at all. I've created a PHP file called "filmdetails.php" that will list all details of a given film:

```
    <?php

    require_once 'dbcon_sakila.php';

    $film_id = $_GET['filmid'];

    $sql = 'SELECT title, description, release_year, rental_duration, rental_rate, length, replacement_cost, rating, special_features, film.last_update, category.name, actor.first_name, actor.last_name
    FROM film, film_category, category, film_actor, actor
    WHERE film.film_id = film_category.film_id
    AND category.category_id = film_category.category_id
    AND film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
    AND film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
    AND film.film_id = ?';
    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $film_id);
    $stmt->bind_result($title, $description, $release_year, $rental_duration, $rental_rate, $length, $replacement_cost, $rating, $special_features, $last_update, $category_name, $first_name, $last_name);

    $stmt->execute();

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '<p>Title: ' . $title . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Description: ' . $description . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Release year: ' . $release_year . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Rental duration: ' . $rental_duration . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Rental rate: ' . $rental_rate . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Length: ' . $length . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Replacement cost: ' . $replacement_cost . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Rating: ' . $rating . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Special features: ' . $special_features . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Last updated: ' . $last_update . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Categories: ' . $category_name . '</p>';
    echo '<p>First name: ' . $first_name . '</p>';
    echo '<p>Last name: ' . $last_name . '</p>';
    }

    ?>
```

The problem is when I choose a specific film (in my browser) it repeats itself but with the different actors in the film.
Example:

```
Title: ALLEY EVOLUTION
Description: A Fast-Paced Drama of a Robot And a Composer who must Battle a Astronaut in New Orleans
Release year: 2006
Rental duration: 6
Rental rate: 2.99
Length: 180
Replacement cost: 23.99
Rating: NC-17
Special features: Trailers,Commentaries
Last updated: 2006-02-15 05:03:42
Categories: Foreign
First name: KARL
Last name: BERRY

Title: ALLEY EVOLUTION
Description: A Fast-Paced Drama of a Robot And a Composer who must Battle a Astronaut in New Orleans
Release year: 2006
Rental duration: 6
Rental rate: 2.99
Length: 180
Replacement cost: 23.99
Rating: NC-17
Special features: Trailers,Commentaries
Last updated: 2006-02-15 05:03:42
Categories: Foreign
First name: JUDE
Last name: CRUISE
```

and so on...

How do I prevent this? Do I really have to make more SELECT statements?

Comment: How do you anticipate that MySQL will return a films information if the film has more than one actor? It's a One-to-Many relationship and so the Many must be returned causing the One to repeat.

Comment: Rossco posted the answer but I'd advise you to look into how databases fetch and return results. Make sure you understand aggregate functions because they're very common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a One-to-Many relationship between Films and Actors, you are going to get multiple results. One record for each Actor. This is the nature of an RDBMS.

A solution would be to take the `actor` table out of your query, and in your `While` loop query the `actor` table alone with the `film_id` (which you would need to return in your initial query). You can then have a separate loop through the results of the `actor` query and add them into your page.

I'm rusty on PHP, but it would look something like:

```
<?php

    require_once 'dbcon_sakila.php';

    $film_id = $_GET['filmid'];

    $sql = 'SELECT film_id, title, description, release_year, rental_duration, rental_rate, length, replacement_cost, rating, special_features, film.last_update, category.name 
        FROM film, film_category, category
        WHERE film.film_id = film_category.film_id
            AND category.category_id = film_category.category_id            
            AND film.film_id = ?';

    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $film_id);
    $stmt->bind_result($title, $description, $release_year, $rental_duration, $rental_rate, $length, $replacement_cost, $rating, $special_features, $last_update, $category_name);

    $stmt->execute();

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo '<p>Title: ' . $title . '</p>';
        echo '<p>Description: ' . $description . '</p>';
        echo '<p>Release year: ' . $release_year . '</p>';
        echo '<p>Rental duration: ' . $rental_duration . '</p>';
        echo '<p>Rental rate: ' . $rental_rate . '</p>';
        echo '<p>Length: ' . $length . '</p>';
        echo '<p>Replacement cost: ' . $replacement_cost . '</p>';
        echo '<p>Rating: ' . $rating . '</p>';
        echo '<p>Special features: ' . $special_features . '</p>';
        echo '<p>Last updated: ' . $last_update . '</p>';
        echo '<p>Categories: ' . $category_name . '</p>';


        $actorsql = 'SELECT actor_id, first_name, last_name
            FROM film_actor, film
            WHERE film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id                 
                AND film_actor.film_id = '.$film_id.';';

        $actorstmt = $link->prepare($actorsql);
        $actorstmt->bind_param('i', $actor_id);
        $actorstmt->bind_result($actor_id, $first_name, $last_name);

        while ($actorstmt->fetch()) {
            echo '<p>Actor: ' . $first_name . ' ' . $last_name . '</p>';
        }
    }

?>
```

Again... rusty with php, but that's the basic idea.  This will print the movie details and then run through the actors in the film and print those one by one beneath the movie info.

Comment: Can you please explain me the loop part or give me an example?

Comment: Thanks but it's not working. It says this line:  $stmt->bind_param('i', $film_id); is preventing it to run but I can't tell why though. Heck, I'll just send my assignment now.

Comment: Yea... php... bind_param... I added film_id into the results of the initial query and apparently that is a problem for bind_param. Take film_id out of the initial query and then figure out how to get the film_id from the $stmt (I assume it's the index of the array) and use that in the second query to get the actors for the film. The important part is the separate queries to keep dupes out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY film_actor.actor_id` at the end of your SQL statement